# Angular slickgrid column filter box alignment issue

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slickgrid version **2.19.0** to show my list of data. Here I have a number of columns with filter options. When I scroll the horizontal bar & expand the filter row, the filter area alignment is not matched with each column header. **The same issue happening in the sample angular slickgrid.**

https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/resize-by-content

**Step to reproduce:**

- Collapse filter row by using toggle filter row option in hamburger
  menu.
- Scroll the list horizontally to view the some other columns.
- Expand filter row by using toggle filter row option in hamburger
  menu.

**Current behaviour:**
After the above steps,the filter row showing(maintaing) the columns while collapsing the filter row.

**Expected behaviour:**
It has to show the visible columns with appropriate filter row.

[image]

Comment: I know you are new to Stack Overflow but you must provide more details to your question and optionally code of what you tried as well. Sadly you just won't get answers, unless you update your questions with steps & code of what you tried, including from me the author of Angular-Slickgrid. I cannot help you with this question, it lacks information

Comment: @ghiscoding Question updated.

Comment: ok I see that's very minor, you can open a bug in the lib. I have seen such problem in the past and the horizontal scroll just get out of sync because when you toggle it recreates all the filters. a simple fix (internal to the lib) is to call `grid.scrollColumnIntoView(0)` to scroll back on top-left of the grid